# How to call Matlab

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

I have problem. I don't know what is the code to call Matlab by using VBA excel.

I tried using

```
matlabinit
```

But after I run it, it doesn't work and there was an error message `"sub or function not defined`"

ouh guys, i have this code, but i cannot run it.

```
Sub jadwal()
'*************************************************************
'Unprotect sheets
'*************************************************************
Sheets("Hasil_jadwal_baru").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
'*************************************************************
'Clear the previous schedule
'*************************************************************
Sheets("Hasil_jadwal_baru").Select
Range("A1:CG14").Select
Selection.ClearContents
'*************************************************************
'Clear the previous variable in MATLAB and set up the application
'*************************************************************

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Run "matlabinit"
MLEvalString "clear;"
MLEvalString "clc;"
'*************************************************************
'Send input to MATLAB
'*************************************************************
MLPutMatrix "ic_april", Range("ic_april")
MLPutMatrix "ic_juni", Range("ic_juni")
MLPutMatrix "ic_sept", Range("ic_sept")
MLPutMatrix "ic_libur_april", Range("ic_libur_april")
MLPutMatrix "ic_libur_juni", Range("ic_libur_juni")
MLPutMatrix "ic_libur_sept", Range("ic_libur_sept")
'*************************************************************
'Solve the problem via MATLAB and LP-SOLVE
'*************************************************************
MLEvalString "fixuntukmin"
'*************************************************************
'Send the result to EXCEL
'*************************************************************
MLGetMatrix "hasil_jadwal", "Hasil_jadwal_baru"
MatlabRequest
'*************************************************************
'Close MATLAB
'*************************************************************
MLClose
MLAutoStart "no"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'*************************************************************
'Finish Alarm
'*************************************************************

'*************************************************************
'Reprotect sheets
'*************************************************************
Sheets("Hasil_jadwal_baru").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True

End Sub
```

can you help me??

Comment: Are you using the spreadsheetlink addin? Check if you have added it to your VBA references.

Comment: I am not an expert in matlab but I believe, to call a matlab function in VBA, you need to first bind with it either using Early Binding as @Dan suggested or via Late Binding using `CreateObject`. See this link http://www.mathworks.in/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f135590.html#f133975 This link is for vb.net but will give you a fair idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to add a reference to Spreadsheet link EX in your VBA code. Select tools -> references and then tick the spreadsheet link EX library. After that it should work.

Alternately you can call addin functions without adding references using application.run. So try  `application.run "matlabinit"`. But I think in this case adding a reference is preferable as you are unlikely to be distributing a spreadsheet calling matlab.

Also have you made sure the addin is installed? In excel 2010 click on the developer tab, choose addins (with the big gold gear icon) and tick the Spreadsheet Link Ex Ver... for use with Matlab. Then go into VBA and add the reference as described above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? What error are you getting, the same error? Did you try to add the reference like I suggested? Because you will need it for MLEvalString etc otherwise you have to call all those matlab functions with application.run.

Comment: Mr, if version of matlab will effect or not? because, I had ever asked to my friend, and he said that maybe my matlab version is not compatible. do you agree?

Comment: I think that you need the Spreadsheetlink excel addin and you need to add a reference to it. Have you tried this? I doubt very much that it is a matlab version issue, the issue may be that you do not own the spreadsheetlink excel addin / toolbox. To check if you have the toolbox type ver in matlab and check if Spreadsheet Link EX is listed. If it is, then I am positive that you have not added a reference in VBA. have you?

Comment: I have had list : Spreadsheet Link EX Version 3.0.3, but i dont know what happend why i cannot run the code.

Comment: in the window that you are writing you vba code: Select tools -> references and then tick the spreadsheet link EX library.

Comment: ok thanks you Mr. but I still have problem, how can I use code MLGETmatrix to get matrix from matlab and i will take in specific sheet and cell??

Comment: MLGetMatrix "MatlabVariable", "ExcelRange". Please read the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/exlink/mlgetmatrix.html